# How to normalize a vector used for features extraction from an image?

Tags: image, matlab, vector, normalize

My actual vector has 110 elements that I'll use to extract features from images  in matlab, I took this one (`tb`) to simplify

```
tb=[22.9 30.0 30.3 27.8 24.1 28.2 26.4 12.6 39.7 38.0];
normalized_V = tb/norm(tb);
I = mat2gray(tb);
```

For `normalized_v` I got `0.2503 0.3280 0.3312 0.3039 0.2635 0.3083 0.2886 0.1377 0.4340 0.4154`.

For `I` I got `0.3801 0.6421 0.6531 0.5609 0.4244 0.5756 0.5092 0 1.0000 0.9373` which one should I use if any of those 2 methods and why, and should I transform the features vector to 1 element after extraction for better training or leave it as a 110 element vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalization can be performed in several ways, such as the following:

- **Normalizing the vector between 0 and 1.** In that case, just use:`(tb-min(tb))/max(tb)`
- **Making the maximum point at 1.** In that case, just use: `tb/max(tb)` (which is the method that you have been used before).
- **Making the mean 0 and the standard deviation as 1.** This is the most common method for using the returned values as features in a classification procedure and thus, I think that it is the one that you *should* use right now: `zscore(tb)` (or `(tb-mean(tb))/std(tb)`).

So, your final values would be:

```
zscore(tb)

ans =
-0.6664
 0.2613
 0.3005
-0.0261
-0.5096
 0.0261
-0.2091
-2.0121
 1.5287
 1.3066
```

**Edit:**

In regard to your second question, it depends on the number of observations. Every single classifier takes an `MxN` matrix of data and an `Mx1` vector of labels as inputs. In this case, `M` refers to the number of *observations*, whereas `N` refers to the number of *features*. Usually, in order to avoid over-fitting, it is recommended to use a number of features less than the tenth part of the number of observations (i.e., the number of observations must be `M > 10N`).

So, in your case, if you use the entire 110-set of features, you should have a minimum of 1100 observations, otherwise you can have problems with over-fitting.

Comment: Regarding the first part,is there a reason why zscore is more often used in classification?and regarding the second part i do think that getting it down to 1 sample element is the way to go then,cat should do it right.

Comment: @koko The z-score normalization is used in order to make the features equally important among them, due to the elimination of hte offset and making the variation os all of them (standard deviation) as the unit. However, normalization is applied when you use more than 1 feature. If you don't use more than 1 feature, it has no sense.